# download multiple document from document library

Tags: document-library, document, custom-actions, download

I want to download multiple documents from document library. I select several documents and then click on 'download' icon present in ribbon. It should download all files  and retain its metadata. 'Download' should be custom action in ribbon. Can anyone please provide me custom code for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's more a case of LMGTFY - [Here's a complete tutorial plus a .wsp to add this function.](http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2010/05/08/sharepoint-2010-download-as-zip-file-custom-ribbon-action.aspx)

**To get some basic understanding**

Since you can't download multiple files in one response, you need to package them in a `.zip` for example. What you have to do is getting the `byte[]` foreach file and package them together. Then add created `.zip` to the response to invoke a download dialog.

Comment: I also got another link while googling
http://adicodes.com/download-files-as-zip-file-in-sharepoint/
This blog is reference of same blog you provided, but in this blog he changed a code little bit. can you please help where exactly code need to be changed wrt your link

Comment: There is a problem when you are not at root level. The comments in the blog I referred are giving a lot of extra information. Example - http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2010/05/08/sharepoint-2010-download-as-zip-file-custom-ribbon-action.aspx#id_987508c8-992b-4934-9a2c-ffc6ed641040

Comment: yes, so where exactly we need to make code change if I have to do same in subsite? code is provided in link provided by me.. but i cannot judge where exactly change need to be made(in which file)

Comment: as written in the comment I linked in my previous comment "I changed Ln36 in CustomAction.js to 
form.setAttribute("action", this.site.get_url() + "/_layouts/deviantpoint.downloadzip/downloadzip.aspx"); 

and Ln16 in DownloadZip.aspx.cs to 
string docLibUrl = fullDocLibSourceUrl;" -- See more at: http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2010/05/08/sharepoint-2010-download-as-zip-file-custom-ribbon-action.aspx#id_987508c8-992b-4934-9a2c-ffc6ed641040

Comment: if you want it to work for document library webparts you have to make the changes described in this comment - http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2010/05/08/sharepoint-2010-download-as-zip-file-custom-ribbon-action.aspx#id_fa7e926d-6caa-4c77-a5aa-102681dfbc46

Comment: Do we have any limitation if in document library we have 10 folder and 20 files , i select 7 files and 2 folder and click on download as zip? Also where does this get saved after downloading and by which name? like does it get saved on my desktop with folder name download or zip or some other name?

Comment: as i neither build nor implemented this solution, you have following options: implement it yourself and test, read the documentation, ask the developer

Comment: This wsp is not working for SP 2013 on-premises version.I have tried this. but the custom action is not visible, its disabled.

Comment: Link is dead anyway